# Django: POST and GET request and rendering on a template

Tags: python, django, post, get, request

I'm probably lost in a glass of water but at the moment I can't figure it out. I'm working on a restaurant capstone project where the client is able to see a menu page, a purchase page and the owner of the restaurant after login is able to manage and enter a new recipe and create his personal menu. What I'm trying to do is: when the owner of the restaurant submits a POST request where he entered the recipe, i want that the recipe appear also in the page where is the menu. In this way is able to update new recipe and change maybe the old one. (I copy model, form and view code for a complete overview):

form.py

```
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Recipe
    fields = '__all__'
```

model.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

View.py

```
def recipeEntry(request):
recipe_menu = Recipe.objects.all()
form = RecipeForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return redirect("recipe")

context = {'form':form, 'recipe_menu':recipe_menu}
return render(request, 'inventory/recipe.html', context)
```

recipe.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Recipe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post", action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Add Recipe">
    </form>

    {% for rec in recipe_menu %}
    <div>
        <p>Recipe: {{rec.name}}</p>
        <p>Ingredient :{{rec.ingredients}}</p>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment the part of submitting the POST request it works so is only the second part that don't works. I tried a bit few solution but i don't understand what to do. I thought also to create a GET view for the menu page but i need to pass an URL for get the data and i didn't works.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I don't get which part you say it didn't work. I see you are redirecting the request if the form is valid and also if the form is invalid. So either way it will go to the recipe view. But you don't say your view which recipe you want to show. So I assume recipe view is a list of recipes?

Comment: I want that the list of recipes submitted with the post method in the recipe.HTML is rendered to the menu page. That is basically what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You must try with explicitly instantiate empty form when it's not a post request :*

```
def recipeEntry(request):
    recipe_menu = Recipe.objects.all()
    # form = RecipeForm() Not here yet

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Instantiate form with request.POST
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("recipe")
    else:  # Explicitly write else block
        # Instantiate empty form for get request
        form = RecipeForm()

        context = {'form':form, 'recipe_menu':recipe_menu}
        return render(request, 'inventory/recipe.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you Rvector i learned one thing new about POST and GET.